# Delegate Function .net

Tags: vb.net, delegates

Having problem understanding Delegate error. Error says expression expected, How do I fix? Thanks for any help.

Here is the offending line (#259)....

```
mylist.ForEach(Delegate Function(P As linkItem) As System.Char[] )
```

Here is the entire code.

```
<script language="VB" runat="server">  

    Function sectionTitle(ByRef f As String)

        'Open a file for reading
        'Dim FILENAME As String = Server.MapPath("index.asp")
        Dim FILENAME As String = f

        'Get a StreamReader class that can be used to read the file
        Dim objStreamReader As StreamReader
        objStreamReader = File.OpenText(FILENAME)

        'Now, read the entire file into a string
        Dim contents As String = objStreamReader.ReadToEnd()

        'search string for <title>some words</title>     
        Dim resultText As Match = Regex.Match(contents, "(<title>(?<t>.*?)</title>)")
        'put result into new string
        Dim HtmlTitle As String = resultText.Groups("t").Value

        Return HtmlTitle

        ' If HtmlTitle <> "" Then
        'Response.Write(HtmlTitle)

        ' Else
        'Response.Write("<ul><li>b: " & contents & "</a></li></ul>")

       ' End If

    End Function


    Public Class linkItem

        Public myName As String
        Public myValue As String

        Public Sub New(ByVal myName As String, ByVal myValue As String)


            Me.myName = myName

            Me.myValue = myValue


        End Sub 'New 

    End Class 'linkItem



    Sub DirSearch(ByVal sDir As String)

        Dim d As String
        Dim f As String
        Dim mylist As New List(Of linkItem)


        Try
            For Each d In Directory.GetDirectories(sDir)
                'Response.Write("test c")

                For Each f In Directory.GetFiles("" & d & "", "index.asp")

                    'Response.Write("test a")                   
                    Dim sTitle As String = sectionTitle(f)
                    'remove wilbur wright college - from sTitle string
                    sTitle = Regex.Replace(sTitle, "My College - ", "")
                    'print section title - must come before search n replace string
                    f = Regex.Replace(f, "C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\pathtosite\\", "")
                    'add to list
                    mylist.Add(New linkItem(f, sTitle))
                    'print links as list
                    'Response.Write("<ul><li><a href='" & f & "'>" & sTitle & "</a></li></ul>")
                    mylist.ForEach(Delegate Function(P As linkItem) As System.Char[] ) 
                    If (True) Then
                        Response.Write("<ul><li><a href='" & P.myValue & "'>" & P.myName & "</a></li></ul>")
                    End If


                Next
                DirSearch(d)
            Next
        Catch excpt As System.Exception
            'Response.Write("test b")
            Response.Write(excpt.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub




</script>
<%     
    'Dim sDir As New DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath(""))

    Call DirSearch((Server.MapPath("")))
%>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on what you are trying to do. You are missing the function body. But you probably need to change that line to something like this:

```
mylist.ForEach(AddressOf ProcessLink)
```

Then you need to create a sub, like so:

```
Sub ProcessLink(li As linkItem)
    ' Do stuff here
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the function body is missing.

Answer (score 0):

The delegate is missing the function code to execute (as @Yogendra indicates) and also, VB.Net does not understand char[]. Perhaps you mean char().